# Error with the wifi and the network manager in the Deepin launcher

Tags: wifi, network-interface, networkmanager, deepin, launcher

I have a very strange error, it turns out that my Wi-Fi interface is not being managed by the Wi-Fi icon of my launcher in Deepin 15.5. It does not show me other Wi-Fi networks nearby, however the command iwlist wlp3s0 scan shows me several wifi, so the interface is up. It responds well to the use of ifconfig wlp3s0 up or down, however if I give it down it does not reflect it in the launcher of the wifi. It's as if my launcher was managing another interface through the network manager. It is uncomfortable because I have to connect to wpa_supplicant, it is clear that the device works. When I turn it off by the launcher in ifconfig -a it's still up. service networkin status return active(exited). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixes the problem. In my `NetworkManager` config file, I replaced the line:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:ap0;interface-name:wlp3s0;
```

by:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:ap0;
```

I used a script to create the Wi-Fi configuration, I think that this was the cause of the modification in my `NetworkManager.conf`.